# Running Multiple Magento Stores With Add-on Domains - New Mage::run() parameters don't fit tutorial's expectations

Tags: magento

So I have BroadStore.com and NicheStore.com. BroadStore.com is my primary domain and NicheStore has been added as an add-on. Magento is installed in /public_html/ (BroadStore.com root).

[I'm following this tutorial to get everything set up](http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/#secure-checkout-for-each-store) but at a certain point it requires that I :

```
//With the index.php file still open, replace the following line of code:
Mage::run();
//…with the following:
Mage::run('shoes', 'website');
```

But my current index.php has the following code instead, by default:

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Any ideas? Currently - with index.php unedited but the rest of the tutorial followed through - NicheStore.com redirects everything to BroadStore.com

All help appreciated; thanks in advance. This is one heavy piece of software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to change the index.php at the bottom to look something like:

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']){
case 'NicheStore.com':
    Mage::run("niche");
    break;
default:
    Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
}
```

Or something similar ... may not be the best solution but it worked for me.

Comment: sorry didn't read the tutorial that you posted, not sure if my solution would work for you. This is was I use for multiple stores not off of subdommains but different domains pointing to the same directory

Comment: To readers: The switch statement method provided by sbditto85 proved useful and, along with http://blog.magentomagik.com/how-to-setup-manage-multiple-stores-in-magento-commerce/ , solved my problem after some hacking. I now have one 'Website' and two 'Stores' - each with an independent domain of their own. The Tracking/Stats possibilities will be fun...

Comment: Relevant link about how to set these values using htaccess etc, http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/multiple-website-setup

Answer (score 0):

I used the method (method 2) described [here](http://docs.nexcess.net/multiplestorefronts#method-2shared-directory-for-all-stores-using-pointer-domains) to do my multi-store setup. The requirement was to set up a multi-store site with different stores for different brands under subdomains, a la a.domain.com and b.domain.com. Worked perfectly under Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu Server with PHP 5.3.2 and Magento 1.7 using the SetEnvIf method.